# SQL sorting & grouping

Tags: sql

I have 1 table with 3 columns: CustomerID, OrderID and Value. >> see left side of the image
Can I use SQL to output the table sorted by highest values BUT also grouped by customerID like on the right hand side of the image?

Many thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
order by max(value) over (partition by customerid) desc,  -- highest values first
         customerid,                                      -- keep customers together
         value desc
```